# Ant Design CSS class list/documents

Tags: antd

In MUI for each component there is a section with CSS class list that one can override, I can't find the same for Ant Design, people seem to search in Dev tools inspector but is that the only approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newest antd versions if you want to overwrite styles by using antd default `css` classes so yes, you'll need to search for desired class in dev tools, this works but it's not the best sollution.

You can change component styles in many different ways:

You can change [token](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) config:

```
<ConfigProvider
    theme={{
      token: {
        // primary seed Token
        colorPrimary: '#00b96b',
        borderRadius: 2,

        // Alias Token
        colorBgContainer: '#f6ffed',
        Button: {
          primaryShadow: '0 2px 0 rgb(255, 0, 0)'
        } 
      },
    }}
  >
    <Button type="primary">Primary</Button>
  </ConfigProvider>
```

You can use component `style` prop:

```
<Button type="primary"
  style={{
    color: 'red'
  }}
>
  Primary Button
</Button>
```

My favorite way is to use a custom `js/ts` file to handle component styles:

```
// 
// component file
//
import Styles from 'path/to/styles.js|ts'

...

const S = Styles()

...

<Button type="primary"
  style={ S.Button }
>
  Primary Button
</Button>

//
// styles.ts file
//
import { CSSProperties } from 'react'
import { theme as antdTheme } from 'antd'

// types
type StylesType = {
  Button: CSSProperties
  OtherComponent: CSSProperties
}

function Styles(): StylesType {
  const { useToken } = antdTheme
  const { token: theme } = useToken()

  const Button: CSSProperties = {
     color: theme.colorError
  }

  const OtherComponent: CSSProperties = {
    ....
  }

  return {
    Button,
    OtherComponent
  }
}

export default Styles
```

Or even use custom `css` classes:

```
// component
<Button type="primary"
  className={'customStyledButton'}
>
  Primary Button
</Button>

// css file
.customStyledButton {
  // don't forget to add !important so 
  // antd will not overwrite your styles
  color: red !important; 
}
```

Hope this helps :)